# Can I use more than one value for the CSS animation-delay property?

Tags: css

Can I make the animation run after 1 second and 40 milliseconds, without writing it in milliseconds, like:`animation-delay: 140ms;`

Comment: Answer is NO, why you even want to do that?

Comment: If you try to look at the refrences at The Mozilla Developer Network "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay", get down to the Syntax, you'll see this `animation-delay: 2s, 4ms`, I just got stuck if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, try writing like this

```
animation-delay: 1.4s;

-webkit-animation-delay:1.4s; /* Safari and Chrome */

animation-delay: 1.4s; /* W3C and Opera */

-moz-animation-delay: 1.4s; /* Firefox */
```

or even like this

```
animation-delay: 1s, 40ms;

-webkit-animation-delay:1s, 40ms; /* Safari and Chrome */

animation-delay: 1s, 40ms; /* W3C and Opera */

-moz-animation-delay: 1s, 40ms; /* Firefox */
```

Look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay

Comment: He wants to write 1sec 40ms, not possible

Comment: @Mr.Alien OK sir, i got it.

Comment: I saw this link, and that's why I asked this question, `animation-delay: 1s, 40ms;` doesn't work..